# Power conversion to temperature

Tags: electricity, temperature, heat-conduction

When an electrical shortcut happens at a wire, the wire heat up to melting point
[example](https://youtu.be/DJOX0c60wQE)   Is there a formula to calculate temperature reached?

Comment: For a copper wire, it would be the melting point of copper. For an aluminum wire, it would be the melting point of aluminum, For ...

Comment: The heat transfer principles are reviewed [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/638040/146039), for example.

Comment: Chemomechanics Have you watched the video?